# How to sequentially call an input task and other tasks in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to override the `it:run` task in sbt so that it would run two other tasks (actually three if you include logging) in sequence. The first of these tasks is to provision the application (`it:provision`) and the second are to actually run the tests (`it:test`).

I started of with a simple `Task[Unit]` for my custom `provision` task.

```
lazy val provision = taskKey[Unit]("Provisions the application in an environment based on the configuration.")
```

I then defined a function to use for the `it:run` implementation as:

```
def runIntegrationTestsImpl(): Initialize[Task[Unit]] = Def.inputTask {
  Def.sequential(
    provision in IntegrationTest,
    Def.task(state.value.log.info("Running integration tests.")),
    test in IntegrationTest
  ).value
}
```

This worked fine. However what I really wanted was to make the provision task an `InputTask[Unit]`.

So I then changed `provision` to:

```
lazy val provision = inputKey[Unit]("Provisions the application in an environment based on the configuration.")
```

And tried to update the `it:run` implementation:

```
def runIntegrationTestsImpl(): Initialize[InputTask[Unit]] = {
  val parser = DefaultParsers.any.*.map(_.mkString)
  Def.inputTask {
    val prov = (provision in IntegrationTest).toTask(parser.parsed)
    Def.sequential(
      prov,
      Def.task(state.value.log.info("Running integration tests.")),
      test in IntegrationTest
    ).value
  }
}
```

This is as close as I got to it compiling. I didn't really intend on parsing the arguments here but it seemed `toTask` was the only way to get an `Initialize[Task[Unit]]`.

No matter what I try and do I still cannot get rid of the following error:

> Illegal dynamic reference: prov

Which is referring to the first element in the sequence.

I seem to hit this problem a lot with the sbt macros. Is there a way to achieve what I want?